# Why have gvfs mount points in 13.10 changed to the user id rather than the user name as in 13.04

Tags: mount, gvfs

When mounting a samba share in Files (nautilus) in 13.10 I've noticed that the mount point is now `/run/user/1000/gvfs/{name of share}`. Under 13.04 the same nautilus share used to mount under `/run/user/rod/gvfs/{name of share}`.

What was the reason for the change and can it be changed back to using your real name?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gvfs/gvfs_1.18.2-0ubuntu1/changelog) this change was not included in Ubuntu but upstream. I looked at the gitlog of gvfs upstream but didn't found the exact commit that made this changes.

- Upstream changelog: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/log/
- NEWS file: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/NEWS